# Using GOST with Crypt::CBC

Tags: perl, encryption, gost28147

I want to use the GOST encryption algorithm in Perl. I tried using RC4 and Blowfish and it was ok, but I'd rather use GOST and Elijah which aren't supported by Crypt::CBC. How can I use Crypt::CBC interface for encryption and decryption with GOST?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a cipher-Object when you create your [`Crypt::CBC`](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/Crypt-CBC-2.33/CBC.pm)-object. So install [`Crypt::GOST`](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Crypt-GOST-1.00/GOST.pm) from CPAN and use it there.

This works here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Crypt::CBC;

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(-key => 'test', -cipher => 'GOST');
```

Comment: i solve my problem in Gost every algorythm for adding to cbc must contain this subrutin new() encrypt() blocksize() keysize() decrypt(), but i have problem with adding TEA : tiny Encripted Algorythm i cant find a true implementaion of this algorythm in perl what i must do?

Comment: i download tea from this link :https://metacpan.org/module/Crypt::TEA but this cod content a rutin that does not implemented in it such as  Crypt::TEA::setup($key, $rounds || 32) what i must do?

Comment: just install Crypt::TEA from CPAN and you can use it like the others: `my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(-key => 'test', -cipher => 'TEA');`

Comment: but i have this error    Undefined subroutine &Crypt::TEA::setup called at Crypt/TEA_PP.pm line 24, <STDIN> line 1.

Comment: You have some mess with the modules it seems. TEA_PP.pm is the wrong module i think (maybe because of [that](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Crypt-Tea)).

Comment: `Crypt::TEA` and `Crypt::Tea` are apparently different modules!

Comment: you say true but when i changed TEA_PP.pm to TEA.pm i had this problrm yet i think there is not a Tiny Encrypted Algorythm in pure perl that works properly!!!!what do you think

Comment: Possible solution would be to remove/uninstall `Crypt::Tea` and stick to Crypt::TEA, which i suppose should work as expected.